# Simulate delay in Vuex's action method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am writing Vue application for backend which is still in development. For this reason I want add artificial delay to actions. For instance if I submit `sign in`, I want add delay 1 second and then redirect to main application.

this is submit method from component

```
onSubmit() {
  this.loading = true;
  this.$store.dispatch('auth/signIn', this.credentials).then(() => {
    this.loading = false;
  });
}
```

and here is action's signIn method:

```
  async signIn({ commit }, credentials) {
    const result = await authService.signIn(credentials);
    await commit(AUTHENTICATE, {
      authenticated: result
    });
  }
```

as you can see, I call there authService in which method I created timeout block which not work and service returns `undefined`

```
  async signIn(credentials) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('credentials', credentials);
      return true;
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't return anything from your signIn method and setTimeout doesn't block code execution.

If you want to make a blocking timeout, I suggest creating a `delay()` method, like this:

```
function delay(time = 2500) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, time)
  })
}
```

By default it will wait for 2.5 seconds.

You can see a working example in vanilla JS [here](https://codepen.io/wilkoklak/pen/NWNMeVm)

Answer (score 4):

This is what I used for delay. Check https://alesbubblesort.netlify.app/ main.js file.

```
sleepFunction(time) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  }
```